# How to find most common expressions starting with "iron"?

Tags: computational-linguistics, vocabulary, tools, collocations

I want to find a list of 2-word expressions starting with iron:

i.e. ironing board, iron filings, iron bridge

Can you suggest a vocabulary tool for that?

Comment: e.g. "derived terms" in [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iron#Derived_terms)

Comment: www.wordmaker.info   (Select *'starting with'*, then enter ***iron*** in the search box).

Comment: Do you want to include expressions starting with "irony", "ironic" or "ironton"?

Comment: it's easy to find words starting with a given prefix, I would like to find pars of wods that include iron, the most common words that that come after and previously in litteratre. JK answer is awesome, i am just waiting for the website to send me an email so i can activate and search :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [BYU corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org), you can search for `iron* _nn*` where the first part matches words starting with “iron” and the second part matches nouns.

It’s as simple as typing that into the search box, though there are more complicated options available.

The two BYU corpora I use the most are the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/).

Comment: The query `iron* _nn*` has almost no recall on CoCA, it is better to use `iron* *` and filter out artefacts like *iron .* or *iron is* afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [Corpus Query Processor](http://cwb.sourceforge.net/cqpweb.php) or a similar corpus engine with a suitable corpus to answer your question, the query

```
[word="[Ii]ron.*"][word=".*"]
```

and a frequency breakdown on the types does the job.

The more difficult thing is finding a "suitable" corpus, news, science, or literary texts will give different ranking lists.